# Pubnub many private chats in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, pubnub

I am developing an ios app like Tinder. Users can chat only in private 1:1.

Should I have to open one channel for every single "match"? Is this the correct design pattern for this case study? What about performance if i have one channel per "match".

*Match" is when a user matches to another and can start a private chat.

Answer (score 2):

If one person can have multiple matches, you can ask **PubNub** client to open separate channel for each nothing person. So, when you have two matching persons, you take some unique identifiers from both of them and using known algorithm create unique name of the channel for which both clients will subscribe to communicate.
One channel for whole application - really bad idea, because of possible massive flow of data, which for most of subscribers will be useless, because consumer is one of other subscribers.

Comment: Thank you @moonlight . So, if a user has 30 matches will have 30 separate channels.

Comment: @BillDani yes, it will be better to use separate channel for each matching person.

Comment: Are you the author of pubNub iPad Demo App?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the best approach is that every "match" should have it's own channel on which both participants publish/subscribe to communicate.  PubNub has no limit on channels (nor does it charge based on channels), so this shouldn't create a performance or cost issue.

To add access control to the "match" channel (if you want to ensure no one else can access that channel), use PubNub Access Manager, documented here: http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/tutorial/access-manager.html  (use dropdown to change programming language)

If you want to provide chat history, so that the two participants can see messages from previous chat sessions, enable PubNub Storage & Playback, and use the PubNub.History() API, documented here: http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/overview/storage-playback.html

If you want to see when those two participants are connected to the Match channel, use PubNub Presence, documented in the same place.